# Unable to connect Android TV ADT-1 to my laptop

Tags: android, android-tv

I am using a Windows 7 enterprise edition.

I am trying to make some application for Android TV(ADT-1). The issue is my laptop is not able to detect the device using USB Port.

My laptop is able to detect other device like iPhone and all. I have checked "devices an settings" as well but can't find anything.

Can anyone guide me how to make android TV work on my laptop.

Comment: Have you enabled the "Developer options"  hidden menu? To do so, go to Settings, About, tap 7 times on the build number, then go back to home and back to settings again. Now you will find the hidden developer menu, where you can enable the USB debugging.

Comment: In addition to enabling USB Debugging, also make sure your ADT-1 has all the latest updates.  Mine came shipped with SDK 20.  MinSDK in Android Studio for Android TV is 21.  After the updates, my Android TV now has SDK 21.

Comment: How did you connect via USB?  There is no micro-usb port on ADT-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [developer page](https://developer.android.com/tv/adt-1/index.html):

> Make sure you have enabled USB debugging in Settings > Preferences >
>   Developer options > Debugging > USB debugging, so that you can use the
>   Android Debug Bridge (adb) to connect with the ADT-1 device.

You will need to set up the Android developer tools (IDE + SDK) on your laptop, either Android Studio or Google's preconfigured Eclipse.  Start here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Since you are developing on Windows, you will also need to install the Android USB Driver, as described here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html